# Orange Data Mining and Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression, orange

For logistic regression in R can I  get the list of significant factors and other details as we get in R ? In R when we run glm function we get all the details like coefficient and whether the independent variable is significant or not. Can we do similar thing in Orange?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about significance, but [Logistic Regression widget](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/model/logisticregression.html) seems to have an output called *Coefficients*.